# Android Kotlin - Credential Manager sign in - coroutineScope

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin, credential-manager

I'm trying to implement the new sign in method since the old one is what what ever the hell reason deprecated, but the google docs are as always incomplete.

This is the part I'm current at:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
    try {
        val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
            request = request,
            context = this,
        )
        handleSignIn(result)
    } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
        handleFailure(e)
    }
}
```

`coroutineScope` is unresolved referrence

I'm watching this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_jZMDmodG4

and the guy there just does:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
```

and it works for him, but for me `rememberCoroutineScope()` is also unresolved referrence

How to make it work?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Based on Tenfour04's answer, I tried this now:

```
    val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this)

    val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
        .setServerClientId("blaaaa")
        .build()

    val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
        .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
        .build()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        whenStarted {
            try {
                val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                    request = request,
                    context = this@GoogleLogin,
                )
                handleSignIn(result)
            } catch (e: GetCredentialException) { Log.d("pikaboo", "I love google")}
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't start the login process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rememberCoroutineScope()` is what you would use in a Compose Composable. If you are not using Compose, then if you are in an Activity or Fragment, use `lifecycleScope`, and if you’re in a ViewModel, use `viewModelScope`.

From what I can gather from your other questions, you are **not** using Compose, and therefore cannot successfully use `@Composable`. It doesn’t make sense. Compose is a completely different UI system than the traditional views you are using.

Comment: What do I need to import for lifecycleScope?

Comment: If your Activity is a subtype of ComponentActivity or FragmentActivity, or if your Fragment is a subtype of the Fragment class from the Jetpack library, then you can type lifecycleScope and hover over it to let the IDE do the automatic import. I don’t remember what package it is in and am away from computer.

Comment: OK I did:         lifecycleScope.launch {
            withStarted {
                try {
                    val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                        request = request,
                        context = this@GoogleLogin,
                    )
                    handleSignIn(result)
                } catch (e: GetCredentialException) { Log.d("pikaboo", "I love google")}
            }
        } but get: "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body"

Comment: Does it mean I'm forced to use coroutineScope without there even being an example how to do that? What the hell is wrong with those half apes who are working on android?? How hard can it be to provide proper example codes in the docs??

Comment: Where did you get the `withStarted` part? That apparently does not work with coroutines. I guess they expect you to know Kotlin coroutines to be able to use their stuff now, the same way they used to expect you to know everything about Java.

Comment: Because "whenStarted" didn't start the process and it's also marked as depricated, withStarted was suggested so I tried it

Comment: Ok now I see that there is an error in the process, but lifecycleScope works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to obtain a `CoroutineScope`, the most common being either in a suspend function and calling `coroutineScope { ... }` (or `withContext` and similar) or being in a `@Composable` function and calling `rememberCoroutineScope()`.

The latter seems to be what was used in your example.

Comment: Please show an example